# div as high as image next to

Tags: html, css

Please check this fiddle which I made http://jsfiddle.net/2uJKR/80/.

here is the html

```
<div class="wrap">
 <div class="box">
  <img src="http://91ef69bade70f992a001-b6054e05bb416c4c4b6f3b0ef3e0f71d.r93.cf3.rackcdn.com/beautiful-woman-holding-an-open-umbrella-100171690.jpg">
 </div>

 <div class="box">
  <p> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
 </div>
</div>
```

and the style

```
img {max-width: 100%;height: auto;width: auto\9; /* ie8 */}
.wrap {margin:0 auto;max-width:500px;width:100%;}
.box {width:50%;float:left;background-color:red;overflow:hidden;}
.bop p {max-height:100px;width:50%;}
```

My problem is that the right .box is overflowing under image. My imagination is to have the right .box as high as the image next to when zooming.

How could I make it?

Comment: what do you mean by `as high as the image next to when zooming`?

Comment: It looks like your box is already higher than the image.

Comment: @Felix because the image's height is set to auto its resizing according to resolution of monitor. Because of that I dont know how to set the div (named box) next to the image to have same height as the image.

Comment: @Nicholas Hazel I know. Could you type me how can I repair it to have always the same height as the image?

Comment: Will you always know the size of the image?

Comment: @Nicholas Hazel No, never. That's the problem. It's resizing according to monitor resolution.

Comment: Vertical alignment with CSS alone is hard enough already. The problem is, if your images will be changing, you may need to incorporate some JavaScript. Would you like me to post a solution using a script?

Comment: That would be really kind from you.

Comment: One question, cause I think I'm still confused. We would need to modify the text size as well if the image is shrinking and you want ALL of the content to have a 50% width, and height of image. Is that acceptable?

Comment: Yes, I think modify the text size is needed. So make it please as you said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is definitely a tricky answer, and it wasn't fully clarified, but I'll try my best.**

`CSS` doesn't *inherently* have any ability to force same `height` options without a static size.

In order to make this work with `dynamic and changing content`, you would need a bit of `JS magic`.

In one example, I have the `font size` staying the same and the content is simply not viewable without a scroll. This will not adjust `font-size`, and just gives the user a scroll bar to utilize.

#### http://jsfiddle.net/X8B4r/2/

In another example, I have the font-size changing based on the size of the `window`. This will not automatically resize the font until you refresh, but it forces the `initial load of the page` to fit properly.

#### http://jsfiddle.net/X8B4r/3/

**Is this a solution that would work for you?**

Comment: Just keep in mind I mapped it to `IDs` so you'd have to do some creative coding to make it work for a bunch of images.

Comment: I understand the JS and I could do pretty much with that when it is made. The only one what I can't do is think up a code. 
Thank you very much again. :)